# How to restore macbook from icloud?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup

I've bought new macbook after hdd crashing of previous one. Is there a way to restore data without repairing old drive? I know that backups of iOS devices are storing at iCloud. What about mac os? I need to restore files only. I dont remember was backupping setted up on previous machine. If setting it is necessary - how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS has the option of backing up to iCloud.

OS X can use [iCloud Drive](http://www.apple.com/icloud/icloud-drive/) to maintain remote synchronised copies of some data. For everything else, you need to have been using [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201250) locally, or a paid online backup solution such as [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com) for disaster recovery.

It is your responsibility to ensure these are active & up to date.

With no backup, then you need to be looking at data recovery solutions. Whether that is software such as [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com) or [Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescue-mac-data-recovery/) or a dedicated [& expensive] Data Recovery Service depends on the actual cause of the HD 'crash' & the value of the lost data.